# How to load Gradle Plugin (with its depenecies) into build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a project that has two gradle files: `build.gradle` and `myPlugin.gradle`

The `myPlugin.gradle` implemented the Plugin Interface. The plugin also has a dependency on [osdetector-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/osdetector-gradle-plugin)

I added the two gradle files beside each other then I tried to apply myPlugin into `build.gradle` as follows:

```
apply from: 'myPlugin.gradle'
```

However, I have got the following error in `myPlugin.gradle` file:

```
Plugin with id 'com.google.osdetector' not found
```

Here is the code for `myPlugin.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

  repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
      compile   'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.4.0'
  }

import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'
apply plugin: HostingMachineOSPlugin

class HostingMachineOSPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{
    void apply(Project project){
        project.plugins.apply("com.google.osdetector");
        //project.configurations.files('com.google.osdetector')
        println project.osdetector.os

        /* Extend the project property to have the class HostingMachineOS */
        project.ext.HostingMachineOS = HostingMachineOS
    }
}

public class HostingMachineOS {

    static family = "Unkown"

    static def setFamilyName(name){
        family = name
    }

    static def isLinux (){
        family == "linux"
    }

    static def isWindows (){
        family == "windows"
    }

    static def isMacOS(){
        family == "osx"
    }
}

HostingMachineOS.setFamilyName(osdetector.os)
```

in `build.gradle` file: I am just doing something like this:

//define buildScript repositories and dependencies then

```
apply from: 'myPlugin.gradle'

task dummy{
  println HostingMachineOS.isMacOS()
  println HostingMachineOS.isLinux()
  println HostingMachineOS.isWindows()
}
```

How can I solve the Plugin with id 'com.google.osdetector' not found?

Comment: Sounds like your `myPlugin.gradle` cannot find plugin with id `com.google.osdetector`, maybe you should add a buildscript section (with appropriate repositories section), in your `myPlugin.gradle` ?

Comment: I did add the buildscript section in myPlugin.gradle but still have the same error? is there a relation between the dependencies in main build.gradle and myPlugin.gradle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common pitfall, to add a plugin to `build.gradle` file you need to add a dependency for the build script itself - not for the project. The following piece of code (added in the file where you apply the plugin) should solve the problem:

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     mavenLocal()
  }

  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.4.0'
  } 

}
```

**EDIT**

Please have a look [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-plugin-to-a-project-from-a-shared-applied-gradle-file/7508) - it seems that if you need to `apply from` third-party script you need to use the full class name (with package). So the files should be defined as follows:

*build.gradle*

```
apply from: 'myPlugin.gradle'

task dummy{
  println HostingMachineOS.isMacOS()
  println HostingMachineOS.isLinux()
  println HostingMachineOS.isWindows()
}
```

*myPlugin.gradle*

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.4.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: com.google.gradle.osdetector.OsDetectorPlugin
apply plugin: HostingMachineOSPlugin

class HostingMachineOSPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{
    void apply(Project project){
        project.plugins.apply(com.google.gradle.osdetector.OsDetectorPlugin);
        //project.configurations.files('com.google.osdetector')
        println project.osdetector.os

        /* Extend the project property to have the class HostingMachineOS */
        project.ext.HostingMachineOS = HostingMachineOS
    }
}

public class HostingMachineOS {

    static family = "Unkown"

    static def setFamilyName(name){
        family = name
    }

    static def isLinux (){
        family == "linux"
    }

    static def isWindows (){
        family == "windows"
    }

    static def isMacOS(){
        family == "osx"
    }
}

HostingMachineOS.setFamilyName(osdetector.os)
```

Comment: you mean I should add this piece of code in myPlugin.gradle or build.gradle? I already added into myPlugin.gradle and still got the same error

Comment: @WaelShowair, in the file where you apply the plugin - as far as I see it's `myPlugin.gradle` - mind that the scope of the dependency is `classpath` not `compile`.

Comment: I copy paste ur code into myPlugin.gradle but I still have the same error, any suggestions? BTW: myPlugin works fine if I add the classpath in build.gradle inside buildscript section -> dependencies

Comment: @WaelShowair, I've edited the answer, please have a look now.