# Can we include buildscript by using script plugins in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I was trying to include buildscript from an external gradle script but constantly getting some error. Then I found this forum subject, but it was discussed in 2012.

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-include-buildscript-block-from-external-gradle-script/7016

Any changes since then?

Here is my code:

**myPlugin.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
}
}

subprojects {

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    /*
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    */
}

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: "../myProject/myPlugin.gradle"
```

Below error is thrown:

```
> Plugin with id 'spring-boot' not found.
```

In order to make it work, I change the **build.gradle** to this code:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
}
}

apply from: "../myProject/myPlugin.gradle"
```

Which works fine.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

No, no changes. This is still valid. I've answered to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081926/how-to-load-gradle-plugin-with-its-depenecies-into-build-gradle/) on SO related to this topic recently so nothing has changed.

Comment: As far as I can see from your answer to the linked question, you included the "buildscript" closure to the external script. Does that really work? Actually my question is the same with the linked one. Maybe I should add some code.

Comment: Yes, it works. Please add the code that shows the simplified problem.

Comment: I added code. But then I found this link, which show how to include buildscript as external script: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/inherit-inject-buildscript-dependencies-into-custom-script-within-subproject/7175/9