# Multiple Gradle Files in the same project using apply from

Tags: gradle, openapi-generator

I'm trying to segregate the gradle tasks to respective gradle files.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'org.openapi.generator' version '4.3.1'
}
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/script/openapi.gradle"
```

openapi.gradle

```
task buildSampleClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "spring"

    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/sample.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
    modelPackage = "com.sample"
}
```

When gradle build is run, getting this error

A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not get unknown property 'org' for root project 'sample' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

But If I move the content of openapi.gradle into build.gradle it works fine.

Not sure what is the issue, could anyone help here please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we include buildscript by using script plugins in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345248/can-we-include-buildscript-by-using-script-plugins-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `plugin dependencies` before your task definition to your `openapi.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:${openapiPluginDependencyVersion}"
    }
}
apply plugin: "org.openapi.generator"

// your task goes here
task buildSampleClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    ...
}
```

`gradle.properties`:

```
openapiPluginDependencyVersion=4.3.0
```